# getopts with all optional arguments

Tags: linux, bash, getopts

In order to run a bash script I need some arguments and flags, since the requirements are pretty tricky I've chosen to use a getopt function like this

```
while getopts ":s:g:r" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        s)
        # Variables that require value            
        VALUE1=${OPTARG}
        ;;
        g)
        # Variables that require value
        MGROUP=${OPTARG}
        ;;
        r)
        # Variables that, if present, set just a flag
        ASROOT=1
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Usage: ./myscript.sh -s value1 -g value2 -r"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

I would like to have all parameters optional so I can write some conditions later in my code, and first two (s and g) with an arguments, the third (r) is only a optional flag. In the future I may need to add additional parametrers, always optional.
Any advice?

Comment: Firstly I'd suggest you to edit the title, as your ask is regarding getopts (bash builtin) and not getopt (gnu alternative). So, as optional parameter, you're saying that sometimes you gona use the options with an argument and sometimes you gona need to use it without argument? Like -s "optional argument"?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. What are your actual requirements?

Comment: Ok, first of all the question is regarding getops, fine for me to edit the title. Second my question specifically regards this line: while getopts ":s:g:r" o; do - the question is: how to have all options not mandatory. An option that require an argument must have it, any option that is just a flag must remain this way. Apologise for ambiguity and hope this helps to clarify a bit more. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2):

Sample script illustrating optional arguments with bash getopts in a style similar to mysql client.  "--" is also supported.

Usage:
script.sh [-u ] [-p | -p] [--] arg1 arg2 ...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Sample script illustrating optional arguments with bash getopts in
#   a style similar to mysql client.  "--" is also supported.
#
# tgage@nobigfoot.com - 5-Oct-2019 - Distribute/use without restriction.
#

# Defaults
username="$(whoami)"
unset password

while getopts ":u:p:" arg; do
  case $arg in
      u)  # Username
      username="$OPTARG"
      ;;
      p)  # Password
      thisarg=$((OPTIND - 1)); thisarg="${!thisarg}"; thisarg="${thisarg:2}"

      if [[ ! -z $OPTARG ]] && [[ "$OPTARG" != "$thisarg" ]]; then
          unset password
          OPTIND=$((OPTIND - 1))
      else
          password="$thisarg"
      fi
      if [[ -z $password ]]; then
          read -s -p "Password: " password
          echo
      fi
      ;;
      \?)
      # Request Help
      echo "Sorry that I can be of no help."
      ;;
      *)
      # Deal with option at end of line
      OPTION=$((OPTIND - 1)); OPTION="${!OPTION}"
      case $OPTION in
          --)
          # Add support for --
          break
          ;;
          -p)
          # Option with optional argument
          unset password
          read -s -p "Password: " password
          echo
          ;;
          *)
          # Invalid argument
          echo "Error; Invalid option \"$OPT\"." >&2
          ;;
      esac
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))

echo "Username: $username"
echo "Password: $password"
echo
echo "Remaining arguments:$*"
echo
```

Answer (score 1):

The optional parameter are optional to make mandatory check `VALUE1` and `MGROUP`. For example:

```
[[ -n $VALUE1 && -n $MGROUP ]] || {
    echo "mandatory paramter missing"
    exit 1
}
```

[getopts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts)